# MySQL/Python Shulze Elections: QUICKLY generate comparison count hash table for separate fields sharing a distinct ballot_id?

Tags: python, mysql, generator

I'm writing election software in python using MySQL as a "learn to code" project.  I am using 5 different election types, with the ability to expand using modular classes.  I was recently stuck on Schulze and IRV, as both of them require that I compare candidate scores on the same ballots, but in order to do so I needed to create a generator object to avoid memory problems generating the list of ballot_ids for each race.  I accomplished this using MySQLdb.connect(cursorclass=cursors.SSCursor). This is what the voting table data looks like for a race on one ballot:

```
                                                   (prime key)
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
| cand_id | score | race_id | ballot_id | user_id | vote_id |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
|       1 |     4 |       1 |         1 |       1 |       1 |
|       2 |     2 |       1 |         1 |       1 |       2 |
|       3 |     3 |       1 |         1 |       1 |       3 |
|       4 |     1 |       1 |         1 |       1 |       4 |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Here's my issue: although my algorithms work and IRV seems to be fast enough, schulze is a different story.  For Schulze to work, I have to generate a dictionary of winning pair results for each combination, FOR EACH BALLOT.  This means that, inside a for loop iterating through each unique candidate pairwise combination, I'm also iterating through and checking every single ballot to see if one candidate is rated higher than the other on that unique ballot, and adding that to the appropriate dictionary key (arranged in combination tuples).  For Schulze, higher scores represent a higher rating here.  Note that the loop doesn't actually iterate through the reverse combinations, I'm just populating the dictionary appropriately as such.
In this case, the dictionary would look like this:

```
results = { (1,2):1, (2,1):0, (1,3):1, (3,1):0, (1,4):1. (4,1):0, (2,3):0, (3,2):1, (2,4):1, (4,2):0, (3,4):1, (4,3):0 }
```

This isn't that bad, until I have hundreds, thousands, or millions of users and ballots that need to be iterated through for each combination pair.  I'm fairly certain this way of doing things is stupid.  My question is: is there some smart way of querying MySQL, using nested selection or some such thing I don't understand, that makes MySQL do the heavy lifting of counting how many people (i.e. unique ballot_id comparisons) prefer cand_id x over cand_id y?  I feel like it might be possible, but the more I try, the more I'm starting to think that MySQL actually can't do this.  Anyway, if someone could help me figure out a way to do this that isn't slow and stupid, that would really make my day.

P.S. As a newb, I don't really know what I'm asking for here, so if anyone has a better title I can use that would be more helpful to other users, I sure would appreciate it. Thank you.

Here's the actual code:

```
def genPairResults_Schulze(self):
    results = {}
    # Generates a tuple of each unique pairwise combination of candidates
    #
    for comb in combinations(self.candidates, 2):
        # Init the dictionary table of comparison results for the above combination tuple and its reverse
        #
        revcomb = comb[::-1]
        results[comb] = 0
        results[revcomb] = 0
        # Formats the candidates into a string as "(x,y)" for use in SELECT command
        #
        formattedcands = self.formatCands([x for x in comb])
        # Queries MySQL to create generator object of every ballot_id in specified race with the above candidates
        #
        genballot_cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT ballot_id FROM votes WHERE (cand_id in %s and race_id = \'%i\')" % (formattedcands, self.race_id)
        for ballot_id in self.genBallotID(genballot_cmd): # Iterates through the generator of ballot_ids
        # Grabs the score of each candidate in the combination from this specific ballot
        #
            cmd1 = "SELECT score FROM votes WHERE cand_id = \'%i\' and ballot_id = \'%i\'" % (
                comb[0], ballot_id)
            cmd2 = "SELECT score FROM votes WHERE cand_id = \'%i\' and ballot_id = \'%i\'" % (
                comb[1], ballot_id)
            # Pulling inside a list of tuples to get the raw int value
            #
            score1 = self.queryDB(cmd1)[0][0]
            score2 = self.queryDB(cmd2)[0][0]
            # Compares scores and adds winner to dictionary hash count
            #
            if score1 > score2:
                results[comb] += 1
            elif score1 < score2:
                results[revcomb] += 1
            elif score1 == score2: # Ties
                results[comb] += 1
                results[revcomb] += 1
    return results


def tally_Schulze(self):
    # Note: high score here represents higher preference, i.e. with a score of 4 vs 3, 4 wins
    #
    pair_results = {}
    path_results = {}
    winner = {}
    # This is the dictionary generated in the function above
    #
    pair_results = self.genPairResults_Schulze()
    candidates = self.candidates
    # I totally stole this algorithm from wikipedia.  BECAUSE I DONT UNDERSTAND SCHULZE
    #
    for i in candidates:
        for j in candidates:
            if i != j:
                if pair_results[(i,j)] > pair_results[(j,i)]:
                    path_results[(i,j)] = pair_results[(i,j)]
                else:
                    path_results[(i,j)] = 0
    for i in candidates:
        for j in candidates:
            if i != j:
                for k in candidates:
                    if (i != k) and (j != k):
                        path_results[(j,k)] = max(path_results[(j,k)], min(path_results[(j,i)], path_results[(i,k)]))

    for i in candidates:
        winner[i] = True
    for i in candidates:
        for j in candidates:
            if i != j:
                if path_results[(j,i)] > path_results[(i,j)]:
                    winner[i] = False

    return winner
```

Answer (score 0):

Where `genPairResults_Schulze` is doing a SQL query for each ballot (eek!) it could/should push all the work to just one database query:

```
select b1.cand_id c1, b2.cand_id c2, count(*) pref1
from ballot b1
join ballot b2
  on b1.race_id = b2.race_id
 and b1.user_id = b2.user_id
 and b1.cand_id != b2.cand_id
 and b1.score > b2.score
where b1.race_id = ?
group by b1.cand_id, b2.cand_id
```